# datanucleus run JDO webapp in Jboss

Tags: mongodb, jdo, datanucleus

I'm getting no where trying to figure how to run a simple test on Jboss using mongodb...
I followed this tutorial:
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/GettingStartedWithJDOOnJbossAS7InSevenSteps
But this example uses a SQL (oracle) not mongodb, so I tried to figure out a way to do it, but nothing...
Can someone help me out on how to install datanucleus on Jboss or tomcat, if it's easier, using mongodb?

I get this error from jboss regarding the PU:

```
jboss.persistenceunit."DN.war#Profiles":
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Profiles] 
Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
...Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Profiles] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
...Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

It seems it assumes this is a hibernate project...

If someone could help me out on how to setup a persistence.xml to use mongodb on a webserver, I would be very appreciative.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Seems you posted this on the DataNucleus forum and someone replied to you  http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7838

Comment: Hi, Yes, i got an answer in datanucleus forum and I could solve the issue by not having a persistence.xml in the webapp, just got a datanucleus.properties where I store all the properties I need.